# Matlab - Two Subplots, single color scale and colorbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

consider the following code

```
x = [-1:0.1:1];
subplot(2,2,1)
imagesc(x,x,abs(x)/100)
colorbar
subplot(2,2,2)
imagesc(x,x,abs(x))
colorbar
```

[image: Code Result]

**What I want to happen** Is that both images will be on the same color scale, and the same color bar I.e., that the left will be mostly blue, while the right one will show the full scale.

Comment: What is the left plot supposed to show to thre reader? It's going to be all blue. (Composing answer, just wondering)

Comment: (Assuming this was just an example you chose, and your real case has more varied data)

Comment: @IanRiley, in my use case, I actually want to show the reader that the left plot has less variability then the right one. So having it more homogeneous blue would be the desired result

Comment: Ah! That use case makes a lot more sense. (Fixed a typo in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Made the range fit both.

```
x = [-1:0.1:1];

subplot(1,2,2)
imagesc(x,x,abs(x))
colorbar
c2 = caxis;

subplot(1,2,1)
imagesc(x,x,abs(x)/100)
colorbar
c1 = caxis;
c3 = [min([c1 c2]), max([c1 c2])];
caxis(c3)

subplot(1,2,2)
colorbar off
```

Comment: Works brilliantly, thank you. One should note that this imposes the second colorscale on the first, and not just equates them, which is what I needed. I wonder if there's a way to create a colorbar for both. If, for example, `subplot(2,2,1)` was `imagesc(x,x,-x)`, for example.

Comment: This edited version takes the union of both colorbars- hows that?