# Single Colorbar for Vertical Subplots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to make the following MATLAB plot have a single colorbar that extends along both subplots.

[image]

Something like this (done manually with the figure editor):

[image]

**Note:** This is different from the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950229/matlab-two-subplots-single-color-scale-and-colorbar).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution. The colorbar can be manually positioned in code but I wanted to keep everything the original spacing. My final solution is outlined below.

**Step 1.** Create the plot with a single colorbar on the bottom subplot.

[image]

```
figure('color', 'white', 'DefaultAxesFontSize', fontSize, 'pos', posVec)
ax(1) = subplot2(2,1,1);
pcolor(x2d, t2d, dataMat1)
shading interp
ylim([0 10])
xlim([-0.3 0.3])
xticklabels({})
set(gca, 'clim', [-20 0])
colormap(flipud(gray))
set(gca,'layer','top')
axis ij
ax(2) = subplot2(2,1,2);
pcolor(x2d, t2d, dataMat2);
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
shading interp
ylim([0 10])
xlim([-0.3 0.3])
set(gca, 'clim', [-20 0])
yticklabels({})
cbar = colorbar;
cbar.Label.String = 'Normalized Unit';
colormap(flipud(gray))
set(gca,'layer','top')
axis ij
```

**Step 2.** Save the position vectors of the two subplots and the colorbar.

```
pos1 = ax(1).Position; % Position vector = [x y width height]
pos2 = ax(2).Position;
pos3 = cbar.Position;
```

**Step 3.** Update the position of the colorbar to extend to the top of the top subplot.

```
cbar.Position = [pos3(1:3) (pos1(2)-pos3(2))+pos1(4)];
```

**Step 4.** Update the width of the top subplot to accommodate the colorbar.

```
ax(1).Position = [pos1(1) pos1(2) pos2(3) pos1(4)];
```

**Step 5.** Update the width of the bottom subplot to accommodate the colorbar.

```
ax(2).Position = pos2;
```

*Wait, I thought the bottom subplot already accommodated the colorbar?* Actually, when setting the position of the colorbar manually (step 3), the corresponding axis no longer scales accordingly. From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.colorbar-properties.html):

> If you specify the Position property, then MATLAB changes the Location property to 'manual'. The associated axes does not resize to accommodate the colorbar when the Location property is 'manual'.

**The final result:**

[image]