# Matlab - Three (or more) Subplots with Single Colorbar with common Color Scale

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

I have at least three subplot which I need to have a single colorbar with common common range. I mean: one colorbar, rightside of the figure, common for all. However, after surfing the similar questions in the net, none of them works for me. Would you please give a solution about this problem? Thanks.

This is a typical code:

```
xx = (1:10).';
xxMat = repmat(xx, 1, 10); 
yy = 1:10;
yyMat = repmat(yy, numel(xx), 1);

subplot(1,3,1)
surf(xxMat, yyMat, abs(xx.^2+yy.^2));
colorbar

subplot(1,3,2)
surf(xxMat, yyMat, abs(xx.^3+yy.^3));
colorbar

subplot(1,3,3)
surf(xxMat, yyMat, abs(xx.^4+yy.^4));
colorbar
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matlab - Two Subplots, single color scale and colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950229/matlab-two-subplots-single-color-scale-and-colorbar)

Comment: @David: Not worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Combining these two answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39950827/2917957, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54740164/2917957

This adjusts the third subplot to make them all the same size and pushes the colorer further out. You might want to play further with the sizes.

```
clear,close

x = -1:0.1:1;

xx = (1:10).';
xxMat = repmat(xx, 1, 10); 
yy = 1:10;
yyMat = repmat(yy, numel(xx), 1);

h = figure(1);

ax(1) = subplot(1,3,1);
surf(xxMat, yyMat, abs(xx.^2+yy.^2));
colorbar
c1 = caxis;

ax(2) = subplot(1,3,2);
surf(xxMat, yyMat, abs(xx.^3+yy.^3));
colorbar
c2 = caxis;

ax(3) = subplot(1,3,3);
surf(xxMat, yyMat, abs(xx.^4+yy.^4));
colorbar
c3 = caxis;

c = [min([c1(1) c2(1) c3(1)]), max([c1(2) c2(2) c3(2)])];

subplot(1,3,1)
caxis(c)
colorbar off

subplot(1,3,2)
caxis(c)
colorbar off

subplot(1,3,3)
caxis(c)
colorbar off

cbar = colorbar('EastOutside');
cbar.Position;

ax(3).Position(3) = ax(2).Position(3);
```